# Where can i find documentation references for previous releases of Tidy

Tags: php, documentation, tidy

This seems to be the current release:
http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Can any one point me to the reference for Tidy Release '6 November 2007'?

Comment: closest i have got so far is the release from 19 September 2007. 

using the wayback machine 
http://web.archive.org/web/20080303061607/http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html

Comment: I searched everywhere but couldn't find it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://examples.joeysmith.com/quickref.html](http://www.webcitation.org/62eYvS4T3)

Comment: And here's the diff from 2007-09-19 to 2007-11-06: http://codepad.org/L5PytljS

Comment: And, just for completeness, http://codepad.org/5a4gO1Wl is a diff from 2007-11-06 to current.

Comment: Just FYI, I obtained it by checking out the CVS repository at said dates and running "make doc" - the quickref is auto-generated.

Comment: webcitation links to the two codepad URLs, in case they disappear: http://www.webcitation.org/62eYzqqPQ (for codepad.org/L5PytljS), http://www.webcitation.org/62eZ3ncAf (for codepad.org/5a4gO1Wl).